# Fully qualified names with Cassaforte

Tags: clojure, cassandra

Is there a way to do a fully qualified table name when using Cassaforte's CQL DSL?

I've currently got this code:

```
(defn get-data-by-user-id [client-name client-id user-id]
    (cql/use-keyspace (get-session) client-name)
    (cql/select (get-session) "some_data"
                (where [[= :client_id client-id] [= :user_id user-id]])
                (limit 1)))
```

I'm curious if it's possible to do something similar to Korma, eg:

```
(defn get-data-by-user-id [client-name client-id user-id]
    (cql/select (get-session) "some_data"
                (where [[= :client_id client-id] [= :user_id user-id]])
                (limit 1)
                (keyspace client-name)))
```

Comment: have you tried (str client-name ".some_data") ?  I am actually not sure but its a guess

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for me, however, I tried @mpenet's suggestion and used keywords `(keyword (str client-name ".some_data"))` which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cassaforte uses/aliases hayt internaly for it's DSL (I authored this lib), so yes probably see:

https://github.com/mpenet/hayt/blob/master/test/qbits/hayt/core_test.clj#L26-L27

or just use a keyword if you don't need the escaping/quoting:

:foo.bar etc

clojure keywords used as cql identifiers are never escaped.